# Can not call Delphi ActiveX method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, delphi, methods, call

I have issue with a Delphi ActiveX control. I create an ActiveX library and then an ActiveX form. I define one function and I want to call this function from JavaScript. But I can't. JavaScript throws an error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'Method1'".

This is the HTML code:

```
<OBJECT id="GetDocsActiveX" classid="clsid:A03962E6-6030-46C0-988D-ADE26BC4BACD" codebase="GetDocs.ocx#version=1.0">
    <PARAM NAME="Color" VALUE="13417386">
</OBJECT>
```

This is the Delphi code *.ridl file

```
interface IGetDocs: IDispatch
{
    [id(0x000000E8)]
    HRESULT _stdcall Method1(void);
};
```

this is *_TLB.pas file

```
IGetDocs = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{8F2BF1C6-98A5-4D6B-A43E-890698A3C91D}']   
    procedure Method1; safecall;
end;
```

and this is file with implementation

```
unit GetDocsU;
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
interface
uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
    ActiveX, AxCtrls, GetDocs_TLB, StdVcl, Vcl.StdCtrls, ShellApi, Vcl.XPMan, 
    IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP;

type
    TGetDocs = class(TActiveForm, IGetDocs)    
protected    
     procedure Method1; safecall;
public
    { Public declarations }
     procedure Initialize; override;
end;

implementation

uses ComObj, ComServ;
{$R *.DFM}
procedure TGetDocs.Method1;

begin      
       MessageDlg('HI from active x', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, mbOK);
end;

end.
```

Can anyone help with this issue. I try to move method in public section in published section without success.

EDIT
here is java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
        var obj = $("#GetDocsActiveX");
        if (obj) {
            obj.Method1();
        } else {
            alert("Object is not created!");
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        alert("Some error happens, error message is: " + ex.message);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked that you can activate the ActiveX object from a stand-alone Delphi app using `GetOleObject` or `GetComObject`?  Btw, readers can't tell from what you've posted whether your j'script is using the correct clsid.

Comment: I register Activex with regsvr32 and get same error.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed at least this one error:

```
var obj = $("#GetDocsActiveX");
```

That looks like a line of jQuery (or similar library) to get the element with the id 'GetDocsActiveX'. But jQuery doesn't return the element directly. It returns a jQuery object that wraps a collection of elements. You try to call the method of that jQuery object instead of the actual element you're looking for.

There are ways to unravel that element from the jQuery collection, but I think it's easier to just get the object using plain JavaScript:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("GetDocsActiveX");
```

or if you enjoy working with selectors:

```
var obj = document.querySelector("#GetDocsActiveX");
```

Comment: It's work now thank you so much for advice. I should not use jquery in this case but i didn't know it. I think that document.getElementById("GetDocsActiveX"); and var obj = $("#GetDocsActiveX"); give same result but i was wrong. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome! It's indeed an easy mistake to make with jQuery. If you like, please read and follow-up on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)